# SQL-запрос для подсчета повторений

Tags: sql

Есть БД с двумя таблицами (упрощено):

Saleserson: **id**, name
Orders: **number**, salesperson_id

Нужно написать запрос, выводящий имена (name) поставщиков, имеющих более 2 заказов (т.е. id которых встречается чаще двух раз в таблице Orders). Получилось подсчитать количество повторений id с помощью запроса

```
select salesperson_id, count(*) from orders group by salesperson_id;
```

В какую сторону дальше курить мануалы?

Comment: В сторону [объединений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `HAVING`:

```
select salesperson_id, count(*) AS c 
from orders group by salesperson_id 
HAVING c > 1;
```